# Using Roslyn to create a netstandard2.0 dll getting runtime errors after successful compile

Tags: c#, dll, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am trying to use Roslyn to create a netstandard2.0 dll, using the code found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/blob/0408271325bb067fd5f84592a545e8280cedff39/src/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Testing/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzer.Testing/ReferenceAssemblies.cs) to compile against netstandard reference assemblies. Compilation succeeds and I can load and invoke the assembly but when I try to reference the DLL in another project using

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="lib_test.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I get the following error at runtime:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
> file or assembly 'lib_test.dll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> File name: 'lib_test.dll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null'

Any hints or idea why this is happening? The code that generated the assembly is as follows:

```
enter code herestatic void Main(string[] args)

{

   string expression = "6 * 7";

   string text = @"public class Calculator

{

    public static object Evaluate()

    {

        return $;

    }

}".Replace("$", expression);

   var metadataReferences = Task.Run<IEnumerable<MetadataReference>>(async () => await Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Testing.ReferenceAssemblies.NetStandard.NetStandard21.ResolveAsync("netstandard", default)).Result;

   SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(text);

   CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("lib_test.dll",

      options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary),

      syntaxTrees: new[] { tree },

      references: metadataReferences);

 

   using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())

   {

       Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.EmitResult compileResult = compilation.Emit(stream);

       using (var fs = File.Create("lib_test.dll"))

       {

           stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

           stream.CopyTo(fs);

       }

   }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why you are doing this?  Why are you creating an assembly this way? "load and invoke the assembly" - how are you doing this?

Comment: I need to create assembly for users based on how they have configured some other software, the syntax tree here is simplified for test purposes. I have used `System.Reflection.Assembly` for loading the assembly and getting of types that I invoke methods on.